# two different root directories with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have those folders on the same directory

```
/front
/backend
```

i want http://beta.domain.com redirect to the /front folder (this is the easy part)
AND http://beta.domain.com/back redirect to the /backend folder.

my problem is if i try to do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/front/
RewriteRule (.*) /front/$1
```

this url http:// beta.domain.com/back is redirected to /front/back  and i dont want this.

i need something like "if there is a ^domain.com/back in the url then the root directory is /backend else is /front"

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^beta\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/front  [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/back   [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/favourites [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /front/$1  [L]

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^beta\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^back/(.*)$  /backend/$1  [L]
RewriteRule  ^favourites/?$  templates/favourites.php  [NC,L]
```

Does this do the job for you? There might be a way to combine the two blocks, but this is simple.

**Update:** add exclusion for 'favourites' special handling

Comment: its works but i have this line too
RewriteRule ^favourites$ templates/favourites.php [L,NC]

if i try to go to beta.domain.com/favourites its says "not found The requested URL /front/favoritos was not found on this server."
(/templates is in /front/templates)

Comment: Then add `RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/favourites [NC]` in the first group (for /front), and `RewriteRule  ^favourites/?$  templates/favourites.php [NC, L]` in the second group. See the pattern yet?